# JSF Request Scope Bean will create new bean per request

Tags: java, jsf, concurrency, scope, request

I have a bean class with the scope type as "Request".

Mine is a single page application and I have defined all the properties/attributes I need to show on the page at classe level in the managed bean. For ex, this is how my class looks like :

```
public class OfferTableContent {

    public String callingApplication;
    public String numberOfOffers;   
    public Offer offer
    public offerLabel
    public HtmlDataTable offerTable;

}
```

As far as I know, properties if defined at class level can give concurrency issues.

However, in my case, since the scope type of managed bean is "request", I am assuming that each new request will create a new instance of bean and so no concurrency issues will be faced. Am I correct in my assumption ?

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly you want in the last line with a question mark in it? It will help you get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, request scoped beans are thread-safe as separate instances are created for different requests.

Answer (score 0):

Every CDI beans are thread safe, meaning that a second thread needs to wait for the first one to terminate before being able to access the bean.

However you don't even have this problem with a @RequestScoped bean because it will be destroyed at the end of the request.